# Converter um Double com mais de 13 casas decimais para String sem perder valores

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, decimal, double

Tenho em C# o seguinte número em Double: `124.00767638369544`. Quando eu, SIMPLESMENTE, coloco `valor.toString()`, o valor vai para: `124.007676383695`, **IGNORANDO** os `0,00000000000044`. O sistema que estou fazendo precisa dessa precisão.

Já tentei forçar região, parse, e uma infinidade de conversões diferentes e nada.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Acredito que siga a limitação do Excel, que... se colocar o mesmo valor em uma célula, também é desconsiderado o `0,00000000000044`.

Answer (score 2):

Ele está arredondando para uma precisão de 15 digitos, que é o padrão do `ToString()` para esse tipo, segundo o link abaixo.

Mas o `ToString()` permite passar parametros de formatação, como a precisão.

Como o tipo `Double` tem uma precisão maior, pode usar assim para ter todos os dígitos:

```
double num = 124.00767638369544
String numString = num.ToString("G17");
```

O format "G" é um número "Geral", e o 17 é a precisão

Também pode tentar o formato "R", que tenta converter para um valor que, possa ser novamente convertido para o tipo original, nesse caso `Double`, sem perda, mas a documentação recomenda usar o "G17": https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#RFormatString

Mais sobre os formatos do `ToString()`: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings